# Compiling wget2 or wget 1.20.3 for win7

Tags: windows, compilation, cygwin, wget

So i have been trying to compile wget in windows 7 but the compilation fails
i installed cygwin 64 , opened cmd , went to wget source code directroy & typed "bash ./configure" , kept facing missing libraries , installed them & repeated "bash ./configure" till it succeeded

after that i typed "make" in cmd , it compiles some files then it fails

this is the output when it fails

> Making all in lib make[2]: Entering directory
> '/cygdrive/c/Users/user1/Downloads/wget2-latest/wget2-
> 1.99.2/lib' make  all-am make[3]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user1/Downloads/wget2-latest/wget2-
> 1.99.2/lib' .lo', needed by 'libgnu.la'.  Stop. 'fcntl make[3]: Leaving directory
> '/cygdrive/c/Users/user1/Downloads/wget2-latest/wget2-1 .99.2/lib'
> make[2]: *** [Makefile:1803: all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory
> '/cygdrive/c/Users/user1/Downloads/wget2-latest/wget2-1 .99.2/lib'
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:1735: all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving
> directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user1/Downloads/wget2-latest/wget2-1
> .99.2' make: *** [Makefile:1643: all] Error 2
>
> C:\Users\user1\Downloads\wget2-latest\wget2-1.99.2>

it seems to fail due to the message :

> .lo', needed by 'libgnu.la'.  Stop. 'fcntl

i tried searching for it with no results

the same error message happens with wget 1.20.3

Comment: have you tried to compile from `Cygwin Terminal` and not from `CMD` ?

Comment: after reading your comment , i tried using mintty but it produced the same error

Comment: the wget 1.91.1-2 build for cygwin has several patches. Have you looked at the cygwin source package for guidance on the compilation ? a alone `.lo` is not normal. probably you are missing a portion.

Comment: the same problem , i downloaded the x86_64 cygwin wget source code from a mirror ftp , made sure that the files are the same as listed here https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/wget-src.html , followed the build instructions which are found in "wget-1.19.1-2.cygwin.patch" , which says "+Build instructions:
+  unpack wget-1.19.1-2-src.tar.xz
+    if you use setup to install this src package, it will be
+    unpacked under /usr/src automatically
+  cd /usr/src
+  cygport wget.cygport all" , the only difference is that the extenstion is now ".o "& ".a" instead of ".lo" & ".la"

Comment: i manually unpacked the source code to cygwin64\usr\src , also the error seems to say " 'fcntl.lo'  needed by 'libgnu.la'. Stop. " if i follow the apostrophe , wonder why fcntl is written at the end though

Comment: it builds fine for me. Have you not Cygwin utilities in the PATH ?

Comment: you mean the cygwin64/bin directory right? if so then yes i did add it to path , otherwise i won't be able to run mintty,bash or make from cmd

Comment: found the error , for some reason configure added a carriage return (0x0D) between the file name and extenstion in both gl_LIBOBJS and gl_LTLIBOBJS in all Makefile , so fcntl.o was written as fcntl 0x0D(in hex) .o , after removing it by hex then trying make again wget successfully compiled , but why did configure add the carriage return in the first place?

Comment: When building for Cygwin, run within Cygwin Terminal and do no patch the PATH, otherwise you risk that utilities external to Cygwin to be used instead of Cygwin ones and you will mess with CRLF vs LF line terminations

Comment: Ok thank you , please write it as an answer so that i can accept it